# Inherited text-indent value behavior when changing display value from block to inline-block

Tags: html, css

Here is my Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xxgkB/

I have a container `<div>` that has one child, a `<p>`

Why does the `text-indent` value double when changing the display value of the paragraph from block to inline-block?

**HTML**:

```
<div class=container>
    <p>Example Paragraph</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
div {
    background: slategray;
    height: 2in;
    text-indent: 1in;
    width: 2in;
}

p {
    display: inline-block; /* Notice the change when removing this declaration */
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`text-indent` is inherited by default. When you make the `p` element an inline block, it becomes part of the first line of the inline formatting context of the `div` block, thus becoming indented by 1 inch. The `p` element itself then inherits the `text-indent` value from the `div` element, causing its own text to be indented by another 1 inch.

From the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html):

> Note: Since the 'text-indent' property inherits, when specified on a block element, it will affect descendant inline-block elements. For this reason, it is often wise to specify '`text-indent: 0`' on elements that are specified '`display:inline-block`'.

The second line of the text of the `p` element appears to be indented as well, because it's the entire `p` element that's being indented, and not just the first line. This is more clearly illustrated [when you give the `p` element its own background color](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/xxgkB/1), and further [when you close the `p` element and add more text after it into the `div`](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/xxgkB/2).

Comment: @Adrift: No problem :) I happen to thrive on answering questions like this - I tend to favor expository answers over "how do I do this in CSS?" (... unless it's a question about selectors!).

Comment: I agree - I'm also more interested in the *why* than the *how* but that approach doesn't seem too pervasive on SO unfortunately .. oh well :]

Comment: @Adrift: I noticed that too - I guess it depends on the nature of the question, and on whom you ask. See [this question on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165882/appeal-a-not-constructive-question), and compare it with [this discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164436/is-there-a-rule-of-thumb-for-objective-questions-asked-out-of-curiosity).