# Display property differences for inline-*something*

Tags: css, display

I noticed that people covered specifics of some display properties in a 1:1 comparison, but there are quite a few that have not been covered in illustrating the differences. Could someone explain the differences between the various inline-*something* display tags?

A more elaborated definition over places like w3schools would do wonders.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The only difference, for any display type that has block and inline variants, is that the `inline-*` display type has the box laid inline (i.e. in an [inline formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#inline-formatting)) while the other has the box formatted as a block-level box, subject to most of the same formatting conventions as other block-level elements in a [block formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting). The difference between a block-level box and an inline-level box is covered in depth [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17500280/what-is-the-difference-between-block-and-inline-block-with-width-100/17500310#17500310).

Everything concerning how the box lays out its *contents* is pretty much the same (the specifics of which, of course, are governed by the display type itself); any other nuanced differences would have been stated explicitly in the spec. As far as I'm aware, there are in fact no such differences.

When in doubt, prefer block-level display types. If you find yourself asking whether inline-level is appropriate, chances are the answer is no. Certain scenarios may prevent a box from ever being formatted as an inline-level box anyway, such as [absolute positioning or floating](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo), or being formatted as a flex item or grid item instead. The result is a direct conversion from the `inline-*` variant to its usual block variant. That is, `inline-block` is converted to `block`, `inline-table` to `table`, `inline-flex` to `flex`, and `inline-grid` to `grid`. Again, this does not directly affect how an element's *contents* are formatted, not as far as the specifications go.

Examples of each display type and its inline-level counterpart follow.

---

In CSS2.1, [section 9.2.4](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#display-prop) describes `block` and `inline-block` as follows:

> **block**
> This value causes an element to generate a block box.
>
> **inline-block**
> This value causes an element to generate an inline-level block container. The inside of an inline-block is formatted as a block box, and the element itself is formatted as an atomic inline-level box.

Note that "block box" is a shorthand for "block-level block container", and a block container is something that can contain block-level boxes.

You can see that both of these two values cause an element to generate a *block container box*, in which its contents will always follow the same set of formatting rules, but *that* block container box itself is either formatted as block-level, or inline-level.

There is one additional difference between `block` and `inline-block`: an inline-block box *always* establishes a new block formatting context; block boxes only do so [under a set of conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35111906/block-level-element-vs-block-formatting-context/35111972#35111972). This does not hold true for any of the other display types that have block-level and inline-level counterparts.

[Section 17.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#table-display) describes `table` and `inline-table` as follows:

> **table (In HTML: TABLE)**
> Specifies that an element defines a block-level table: it is a rectangular block that participates in a block formatting context.
>
> **inline-table (In HTML: TABLE)**
> Specifies that an element defines an inline-level table: it is a rectangular block that participates in an inline formatting context).

The [Flexbox module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#flex-containers) describes `flex` and `inline-flex` as follows:

> **flex**
> This value causes an element to generate a block-level flex container box.
>
> **inline-flex**
> This value causes an element to generate an inline-level flex container box.

And the [Grid Layout module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid/#grid-containers) describes `grid` and `inline-grid` as follows:

> **grid**
> This value causes an element to generate a block-level grid container box.
>
> **inline-grid**
> This value causes an element to generate an inline-level grid container box.

Again, in all of these scenarios, a table, a flex container, or a grid container will behave exactly the same way whether it is block-level or inline-level. A flex container always establishes a flex formatting context for its flex items, and a grid container always establishes a grid formatting context for its grid items.

Comment: It is the third link I follow that says that inline generate inline and box generate box, but the difference is not clear at all.

Comment: how about inline-* in mail html? It seems gmail works with inline-grid, whilst it does not with grid.