# Example of css inline-flex vs. flex

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm reading up on flexbox layout described here:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

The container `display` property can be set to either `flex` or `inline-flex`.  Can point to a resource that shows what happens when either setting is applied?

I tried looking at various tutorials, but all of them use `flex` only.  For example in the css tricks article `inline-flex` only shows up twice.

TIA,
Ole

Comment: Would an explanation suffice? It's a fairly simple explanation - there's really not much to it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27418104/difference-between-displayinline-flex-and-displayflex

Comment: Marking as duplicate based on the accepted answer.

Comment: @BoltClock thanks - good catch.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`display: flex;` causes the flex container to act as `display: block;` in relation to the rest of the page.

`display: inline-flex;` causes the flex container to act as `display: inline-block;` in relation to the rest of the page.

Comment: Super - I just realized that I understand your answer (Deleting previous comment).  So flex lays the containers out in a block layout and inline-flex lays them out inline .... Thanks!

Comment: Got it.  Now all I need are examples.  I'll try to build one in one of the superfly-css repositories: https://github.com/superfly-css

Comment: @Ole Of course I didn't see that edit until after I finished typing out my response :P Glad it worked out!