# Shrink flexbox container to content size

Tags: html, css, flexbox

If you are using a Flexbox layout to layout some items in a row, the Flexbox container takes up the full width of whatever container it is in. How do you set the Flexbox container to only take up the width of it's child elements?

Take a look at the following example:

https://jsfiddle.net/5fr2ay9q/

In this example the size of the flexbox container extends beyond the child element's width. The typical way to fix something like this is `display: inline` but obviously that won't work because then it's not a flexbox container anymore.

Is it possible to do this?

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

p {
  outline: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
Can you make the flex container not 100% width but rather the width of the content itself?

<div class='container'>
  <img src='https://placehold.it/300x300'/>
  <p>
    This is some content hello world testing 123.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I disagree with marking question as a duplicate of [Difference between display:inline-flex and display:flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27418104/difference-between-displayinline-flex-and-displayflex). It's a totally different question: the asker doesn't know that inline-flex is related to their "how do I?" question unless they already knew the answer to their question before asking it!

Answer (score 18):

You can use `display: inline-flex;` (see [Designating a Flexible Box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes#Designating_a_Flexible_Box)):

```css
.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

p {
  outline: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
Can you make the flex container not 100% width but rather the width of the content itself?

<div class='container'>
  <img src='https://placehold.it/300x300'/>
  <p>
    This is some content hello world testing 123.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow how did I not know about `inline-flex`? Is that a standard flexbox feature? I have never even read about it.

Comment: Indeed it is. It's one of the **why do I need this**, 'till you do :)