# Flexbox: row with inline-flex + fixed item width (fixing flex-basis bug): not working inside column layout

Tags: css, flexbox

I want to get a table in CSS with a sticky header (only body scrolls) on Y, and whole table scrolls on X.

According to Michael_B comment on my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51991617/82609) there is a flexbox bug and I have to use `inline-flex` on row + `width` on cells to make sure my row grows correctly.

This leads me to this result:

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.table {
  border: solid black;
  width: 60vw;
  height: 80vh;
  overflow-x: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
  border: solid cyan;
  flex: 0;
}

.body {
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border: solid yellow;
  display: inline-block;
}

.row {
  border: solid red;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

.cell {
  border: solid green;
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">
        cell 1
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        cell 2
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        cell 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">
        cell 1
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        cell 2
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        cell 3
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">
        cell 1
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        cell 2
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        cell 3
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">
        cell 1
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        cell 2
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        cell 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/slorber/wy7poh0L/)

As you can see it's not exactly what I want. It seems my rows do not grow according to their content size even with inline-flex, and this happens only when using a flex column layout on the table.

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.table {
  border: solid black;
  width: 60vw;
  height: 80vh;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.header {
  border: solid cyan;
  flex: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
}

.body {
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border: solid yellow;
  display: inline-block;
  height: calc(100% - 50px - 16px);
}

.row {
  border: solid red;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

.cell {
  border: solid green;
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
}



By removing flex column, using inline-block and calc computations, I almost get the behavior I want, except I'd like the scrollY scrollbar to always stay visible
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">
        cell 1
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        cell 2
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        cell 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">
        cell 1
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        cell 2
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        cell 3
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">
        cell 1
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        cell 2
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        cell 3
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">
        cell 1
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        cell 2
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        cell 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/slorber/ph6rugyf/)

Anyone knows how I could achieve the table layout I want? I'm open for no flexbox solution but I don't want a JS based solution for now.

Comment: So something like this, but with the header row fixed? http://jsfiddle.net/wy7poh0L/7/

Comment: yes, and maybe the yellow/cyan borders adapting to their inner content (here it stays at 100% of the container)