# Element with "display: inline-flex" has a strange top margin

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have two `div` elements, both with the CSS property `display: inline-flex`, as I would like to position them beside each other. At first, the div's appear to be positioned properly.

```css
.userImg{
  height: 3em;
  width: 3em;
  background: red;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.nameOfUser{
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 3em; 
  width: 10em; 
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class = "userImg"></div>
                    
<div class = "nameOfUser"></div>
```

However, once I place some text inside of the `nameOfUser div`, it seems to create some strange top margin which makes the two `div` elements un-aligned from each other.

```css
.userImg{
  height: 3em;
  width: 3em;
  background: red;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.nameOfUser{
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 3em; 
  width: 10em; 
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class = "userImg"></div>

<div class = "nameOfUser">
  <h3>Jaxon Crosmas</h3>
</div>
```

Can someone please explain why this is happening and a possible solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between display:inline-flex and display:flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27418104/difference-between-displayinline-flex-and-displayflex)

Comment: `display: inline-flex` does not make flex items display inline. It makes the flex container display inline.

Comment: Set vertical-align: top;

Comment: ^ Thanks, that solved it.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

With `display: inline-flex` you are dealing with inline-level elements.

This activates the `vertical-align` property, which applies only to inline-level and table-cell elements ([source](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#line-height)).

The initial value of `vertical-align` is `baseline`. This means that inline-level elements position themselves vertically to achieve baseline (text) alignment.

> [***baseline***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseline_(typography))
>
> The baseline is the line upon which most letters sit and below which descenders extend.
>
> [image]
>
> <sup>Source: [Wikipedia.org](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseline_(typography))</sup>

This is your current code structure, with the text you added:

```css
.userImg {
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 3em;
  width: 3em;
  background: red;
}

.nameOfUser {
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 3em;
  width: 10em;
  background: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div class="userImg"></div>
<div class="nameOfUser">
  <h3>Jaxon Crosmas</h3>
</div>
```

The second element shifts down so that it aligns with the current baseline of the first element.

Now add some text to the first element:

```css
.userImg {
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 3em;
  width: 3em;
  background: red;
}

.nameOfUser {
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 3em;
  width: 10em;
  background: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div class = "userImg">text</div>
<div class = "nameOfUser">
  <h3>Jaxon Crosmas</h3>
</div>
```

Notice how the baselines shift to align.

The elements still aren't squarely aligned because the `h3` has default vertical margins. If you remove the margins:

```css
.userImg {
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 3em;
  width: 3em;
  background: red;
}

.nameOfUser {
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 3em;
  width: 10em;
  background: aqua;
}

h3 { margin: 0; }
```

```html
<div class = "userImg">text</div>
<div class = "nameOfUser">
  <h3>Jaxon Crosmas</h3>
</div>
```

---

Here are two quick **solutions**:

**1. Override the default value of `vertical-align`, with any other value.**

```css
.userImg {
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 3em;
  width: 3em;
  background: red;
}

.nameOfUser {
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 3em;
  width: 10em;
  background: aqua;
}

div { vertical-align: top; }
```

```html
<div class = "userImg"></div>
<div class = "nameOfUser">
  <h3>Jaxon Crosmas</h3>
</div>
```

**2. Make the parent a flex container.**

This makes your elements flex items, which de-activates `vertical-align` since [flex items are block-level elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-items).

This method also lines up your elements in a row, because an initial setting of a flex container is `flex-direction: row`.

```css
.userImg {
  height: 3em;
  width: 3em;
  background: red;
}

.nameOfUser {
  height: 3em;
  width: 10em;
  background: aqua;
}

body { display: flex; }
```

```html
<div class = "userImg"></div>
<div class = "nameOfUser">
  <h3>Jaxon Crosmas</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Beautifully written answer :)

Comment: Great answer. But there is a mistake, I think. You mentioned that `flex items are block-level elements` and the very spec you linked to literally states: `However, flex items themselves are flex-level boxes, not block-level boxes.` (Below the "example" section in that part of that page)

Comment: @Arad, yes, you're correct in citing that section of the spec. But then read the very next paragraph: *"The `display` value of a flex item is blockified: if the specified `display` of an in-flow child of an element generating a flex container is an inline-level value, it computes to its block-level equivalent."* So, at a minimum, there appears to be confusion and contradiction. Honestly, though, I think we're just overlooking the deeply technical definitions of these terms.