# Why is the second flexbox container (with a SVG in it) moving up?

Tags: html, css, svg, flexbox

I'm struggling to **understand the behaviour** of the following pen (but I already have a workaround): https://codepen.io/nicoespeon/pen/BOamdJ

There are 3 flexbox containers:

1. the first contains only text
2. the second contains a `<svg>` element and some text
3. the third contains some text and a `<svg>` element

I expect all of them to be aligned. But the second box is moving up.

[image]

**Note: I know that if I wrap all of them in a flex container (e.g. set `display: flex | inline-flex;` to `body`), they get aligned.** But I don't understand how the `<svg>` element is impact its flex container in the second box.

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48117071/element-with-display-inline-flex-has-a-strange-top-margin).

It's due to the fact that `display: inline-flex;` is treated just like any other inline element, with default vertical alignment being `baseline`. Notice that the bottom of the SVG is aligned with the text inside the previous `div`. If you add `vertical align: top` to the `display: inline-flex` items, they'll all be aligned as expected.

Hope that helped! I can tell you that this issue confounded the heck out of me when I first encountered it.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Apply `display:flex;` for body tag. It works.

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
  
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
}

svg {
  background-color: red;
}

body {
  display:flex;
}
```

```html
<div>Without SVG</div>
<div>
  <svg height=40 width=20></svg> After SVG
</div>
<div>
  Before SVG <svg height=40 width=20></svg>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Sampath_Madhuranga/gye5Lz4v/3/

This works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I found the workaround as explained in the issue (will make it clearer though).

My question is: why is that happening? I don't understand why the `<svg>` element is impacting its flex container so we need to wrap all of this into another flex container. Am I missing something?

Comment: @nicoespeon, It wasn't happened due to svg or any other issue. Container div of the elements should be a flex container, otherwise it doesn't work properly. You need to understand the basic application of flex properties. Please visit link below.
https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_flexbox

Comment: Yep, I understand I should put the div boxes into a flex container if I want to control the flexible layout of them. In the case I presented though, div boxes are the flex containers. And I was surprised the second box move up because it contains an SVG, while the others don't. I'm wondering why this happens =)

Comment: @nicoespeon, Not only for svg, I think it doesn't work for any element inside that div such as img, input etc..check.

Comment: You're right, I think if you don't provide a flex container to the div boxes, they get positioned regarding what's inside, even though they are flexbox containers themselves. I was surprised the content was impacting the div position, but it's not just SVG.

I'm closing the issue accepting your answer as it's the correct way to do it. Thanks!

Comment: @nicoespeon, It's my pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

Check this one i hope help you and solved your issue

```css
div {
      height: 100px;
    padding: 0 5px;
    color: white;
    background-color: blue;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    float: left;
    margin: 3px;
}

svg {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>Without SVG</div>
<div>
  <svg height=40 width=20></svg> After SVG
</div>
<div>
  Before SVG <svg height=40 width=20></svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I already have a proper workaround (cf. my message & VSM's reply). I'm looking for the reason behind this behaviour.

Also, I don't want the `<div>`s to be float in that case. It has unexpected side effects. I still want them to be flexboxes.