# How to span two columns on a 3x3 grid with flexbox with paddings?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
.page {
  width: 90% margin: auto;
}

.row-container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.item-container {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 16px;
}

.item-container-2x {
  flex: 2;
}

.item {
  background-color: #e7e8e9;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="row-container">
    <div class="item-container">
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-container">
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-container">
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-container">
    <div class="item-container item-container-2x">
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-container">
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The issue here is with the paddings. It causes the grid on the second row to be misaligned.

I'm using `flex: 1;` for the equal width grid items, and `flex: 2;` next to one with `flex: 1;` for the second row. My understanding is that the flex numbers add up. I'm trying to add them up to 3, but in the second row, having only one margin between the two grid items is impacting to spacing. I'm not sure if this approach is better than defining variable widths for the gird items, but using flex seems simple to me.

I think there's also a problem that I'm using fixed paddings of `16px` with the variable width with`flex: 1/2`. I did try percentage margin and still had the same problem. And I'm having a hard time getting my head around needing to use a combination of padding and margin, and maybe even negative margin.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34644807/3597276

Comment: CSS Grid gutters solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48755146/3597276

Comment: @Michael_B why you don't close it then :)

Comment: @TemaniAfif, because I'm not 100% sure the question is a dupe. Reviewed enough to make the association, but not enough to close. Feel free to go ahead.

Comment: @TemaniAfif At that dupe longhand `flex-grow` is used, which gives another result than shorthand `flex` will, hence it is not fully the same. The issue here is caused by Flexbox more complicated way of calculating _space left_ on flex items where padding is used.

Comment: If you're trying to create a grid, why not use `display: grid`?

Comment: @Michael_B Linked to a couple of answers of yours/ours...the suggested dupe as well, as I find it a good read.

Answer (score 1):

When using `padding` on a flex item, Flexbox has a somewhat more complicated way of calculating the space left, which makes it a little more tricky to make that work.

In this case, and to keep using *flex-grow* for sizing, using `margin` on the flex item's child (`item`) would be simpler. It will give the same output as `padding` does on a parent, with a non-flex child.

Stack snippet

```css
.page {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
}

.row-container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.item-container {
  flex: 1;
}

.item-container-2x {
  flex: 2;
}

.item {
  background-color: #e7e8e9;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  margin: 16px;                                     /*  moved from ".item-container" and changed to "margin"  */
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="row-container">
    <div class="item-container">
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-container">
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-container">
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-container">
    <div class="item-container item-container-2x">
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-container">
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

If you need, or have, to use `padding` on the flex items, you need to compensate for the *removed item's* padding (16px on each side), and add it as an initial *flex-basis* on the *spanned* item.

Stack snippet

```css
.page {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
}

.row-container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.item-container {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 16px;
}

.item-container-2x {
  flex: 2 32px;                                       /*  changed  */
}

.item {
  background-color: #e7e8e9;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="row-container">
    <div class="item-container">
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-container">
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-container">
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-container">
    <div class="item-container item-container-2x">
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-container">
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

In another answer of mine, I made a *flex box table version*, which might help you further. Check out the *"Stack snippet - Flexbox"* sample at this link:

- [Layout a flex box similar to a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48570109/layout-a-flex-box-similar-to-a-table/48580275#48580275)

---

As a side note, and since you mentioned trying with percent value, that is gonna give you some more issues, which you can read more about here:

- [Why doesn't percentage padding / margin work on flex items in Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36783190/why-doesnt-percentage-padding-margin-work-on-flex-items-in-firefox)

And here is some more reading about sizing items with `flex-grow`:

- [flex-grow not sizing flex items as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34644807/flex-grow-not-sizing-flex-items-as-expected)