# Using flex: 1 auto;

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to understand how this affects the flow of items in the flow architecture of elements like in this example:

How do we tell sidebars to share a row since sidebars are ordered on numbers 1 and 3?

There is a codepen live example [here](https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/vWEMWw) and here is a Stack snippet

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;  
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper > * {
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 1 100%;
}

.header {
  background: tomato;
}

.footer {
  background: lightgreen;
}

.main {
  text-align: left;
  background: deepskyblue;
}

.aside-1 {
  background: gold;
}

.aside-2 {
  background: hotpink;
}

@media all and (min-width: 600px) {
  .aside { flex: 1 auto; }
}

@media all and (min-width: 800px) {
  .main    { flex: 3 0px; }
  .aside-1 { order: 1; } 
  .main    { order: 2; }
  .aside-2 { order: 3; }
  .footer  { order: 4; }
}

body {
  padding: 2em; 
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header class="header">Header</header>
  <article class="main">
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>  
  </article>
  <aside class="aside aside-1">Aside 1</aside>
  <aside class="aside aside-2">Aside 2</aside>
  <footer class="footer">Footer</footer>
</div>
```

CSS fragment

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

/* We tell all items to be 100% width, via flex-basis */
.wrapper > * {
  flex: 1 100%;
}

/* We rely on source order for mobile-first approach
 * in this case:
 * 1. header
 * 2. article
 * 3. aside 1
 * 4. aside 2
 * 5. footer
 */

/* Medium screens */
@media all and (min-width: 600px) {
  /* We tell both sidebars to share a row */
  .aside { flex: 1 auto; }
}

/* Large screens */
@media all and (min-width: 800px) {
  /* We invert order of first sidebar and main
   * And tell the main element to take twice as much width as the other two sidebars 
   */
  .main { flex: 3 0px; }
  .aside-1 { order: 1; }
  .main    { order: 2; }
  .aside-2 { order: 3; }
  .footer  { order: 4; }
}
```

Comment: The link in your question doesn't go to a live example, and the existing code sample is suppose to fully be within the question, as a minimal working snippet, not just a fragment of it.

Comment: This answer of mine might give you some idea's, how to control flex items in a row/column manner: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48580275/2827823

Comment: I don't even understand, what do you mean share a row? Like sidebars on their own row? In your pen, both sidebars are already on the same row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens in this case is, item's having `flex: 1 100%` will simply take full width of its parent, and since the parent also has `flex-wrap: wrap`, it will put itself on a row of its own, and force its next sibling to the next row.

At `min-width: 600px` the first media query kicks in, where the two `aside`, when given `flex: 1 auto`, will start sizing by their content (`auto`) instead.

That mean that as long as their summed content is not wider than their parent, they will *share* a row, and then, having *flex-grow* set to `1`, equally share the space left.

*Do note, the `aside` are still ordered by markup as 3rd and 4th item. If their content size differs, both their content size is withdrawn from the parent's width, before the space to share is calculated, which simply mean they might not have the same width.*

*Also do note, if the two `aside`'s summed content will be wider than their parent, they will wrap, as seen in this sample:*

- *https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EExVav*

---

Then at `min-width: 800px` the second media query also kicks in, where the `main` when set to `flex: 3 0px`, will stop forcing itself on a row if its own, and instead be *as small as possible w/o content overflow* (`0px`).

Now, with the same logic as for the two `aside`'s, also `main` is included when calculating the space left, where the `aside`'s will take 1/5 each and the `main` 3/5 of the space left.

*The "dividend" is each item's "flex-grow" value and the "divisor" is the sum of the items "flex-grow" per row, which mean if one of the `aside` would wrap, the `main` and the other `aside` would share 3/4 and 1/4 of their shared row.*

Additionally the rules changing the items `order` kicks in, and `aside-1` and `main` swap position.