# Display types are overridden by unknown source

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a container that contains three elements: one image and two divs:

[image]

I want all images to be inline blocks and have specified so in their classes:

```
 .first_image {
        display: inline-block;
        height: 20px;
        width: 20px;
 }
 .first_div {
        width: 100%;
        display: inline-block;
 }
 .second_div {
        width: 52px !important;
        height: 40px !important;
        display: inline-block;
        background-color: #3798D4;
 }
 .container {
        display: inline-flex;
 }
```

However, when I run and inspect, these are the actual attributes:

1. The container (class case-input is .container)

[image]

2. The first image

[image]

3. The first div

[image]

4. The last div (this one has class `.edit_pen_container` and contains a button)

[image]

The issue is that 1. displays as `flex` although it should be `inline-flex`, 2., 3., and 4. display as `block` although they should be `inline-block`. I really don't see why it changes. Also, the property is not crossed out, so it doesn't seem to be overridden.

By the way, so you can understand my logic, `img` will stay there, div 1 has a width of 100% because it has to take the rest of the div. When a user puts the mouse in div 1, div 2 appears and will take a fixed width (52px) and div 1 will shrink to allow div 2 to take the space it needs. Maybe my logic is wrong but this is what I want to do.

All HTML elements have been added through javascript, so I don't have a DOM hierarchy to show.

Comment: Do you have a working URL we can look at?

Comment: @Gerard Currently on a local server only. I decided to switch all elements to block and use a different approach for the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

> *The issue is that 1. displays as `flex` although it should be `inline-flex`, 2., 3., and 4. display as `block` although they should be `inline-block`... Also, the property is not crossed out, so it doesn't seem to be overridden.*

So let's clarify:

- Element #1 (`.container`) is a flex container. You're saying the problem is that you declared `display: inline-flex`, but the browser is rendering the element as `display: flex`.
- Elements #2, #3 and #4 are the in-flow children of #1. This means they are flex items. You're saying the problem is that you've set these items to `display: inline-block`, but the browser is rendering them as `display: block`.

---

Okay. Let's cover these two points one-by-one.

*Why is `display: inline-flex` computing to `display: flex`?*

Because that's what the flexbox specification requires.

> [**§ 3.  Flex Containers: the `flex` and `inline-flex` display
>   values**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-containers)
>
> If an element’s specified `display` is `inline-flex`, then its
>   `display` property computes to `flex` in certain circumstances: the
>   table in [CSS 2.1 Section
>   9.7](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo) is amended to contain an additional row, with `inline-flex` in the "Specified
>   Value" column and `flex` in the "Computed Value" column.

So `inline-flex` computes to `flex` in certain situations, as described in the table linked to in the excerpt above. That's what is happening in your code. Technically, it is not an override, which is why you're not seeing `inline-flex` crossed out.

---

*Why is `display: inline-block` computing to `display: block` on flex items?*

Again, because that's what the flexbox specification requires.

> [**§ 4.  Flex Items**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-items)
>
> The `display` value of a flex item is blockified: if the specified `display` of an in-flow child of an element generating a flex container is an inline-level value, it computes to its block-level equivalent.

Also note that you cannot control the `display` value of flex items. Once you make an element a flex container, the `display` property on flex items is controlled by the flex algorithm. Attempts to set a `display` rule on flex items are ignored by the browser. That's what you're seeing in your code: `display: inline-block` is being ignored (but, again, technically not overridden, which is why `inline-block` is not crossed out).

Answer (score 0):

There is a great discussion already on Stack Overflow on the difference between flex and inline-flex. [It is an important read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27418104/difference-between-displayinline-flex-and-displayflex) and will help in this discussion.

Basically, `inline-flex` means the container will be inline, whereas `flex` means the container will be block-level. Here's the key, in both cases, [the children are `flex-items`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox#The_flex_container) They will behave in a certain way with certain defaults in place to fit the flex model. You have to style them differently, in some ways, than regular block or inline elements.

See the snippet below for an example.

```css
.first_image {
   display: inline-block;
   height: 20px;
   width: 20px;
}
.first_div {
   width: 100%;
   display: inline-block;
}

.first_div_expanding {
  flex: 1;
}
.second_div {
   width: 52px !important;
   height: 40px !important;
   display: inline-block;
   background-color: #3798D4;
}
.container {
    display: inline-flex;
}
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
}

.set-sized-flex-container {
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 75%;
}
```

```html
<h1>Inline-flex</h1>
<p>The flex container only takes up as much space as it needs and will not force a new line.</p>
<div class='container'>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/20x20" class="first-image">
  <div class="first_div">No expansion</div>
  <div class="second_div"></div>
</div>
<hr>
<h1>Flex</h1>
<p>The flex container will take the full-width of the screen</p>
<div class='flex-container'>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/20x20" class="first-image">
  <div class="first_div">I expand full-width</div>
  <div class="second_div"></div>
</div>
<hr>
<h1>Expanding first_div with Inline-Flex</h1>
<div class='set-sized-flex-container'>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/20x20" class="first-image">
  <div class="first_div_expanding">I expand to take up remaining space</div>
  <div class="second_div"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This answer mostly covers the difference between `flex` and `inline-flex` which, as you noted, is already covered in another post. But, more importantly, it doesn't address the questions in this post.

Comment: Thanks for the added clarity in your response. I was focused more on the practicality and you on the depth and understanding. I appreciate your approach.