# Why is height:auto not working for this image?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a flexbox container with two flex items in it. One is an image and the other a paragraph. I've been trying to resize the image proportionally by giving width:some-percentage and height:auto but it's not working. Please help me solve this.

```css
.item{
  display:flex;
}
img{
  width: 25%; /* not working */
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <img
  src=
  "https://png.pngtree.com/element_origin_min_pic/16/10/16/105802ebe43fe0f.jpg"/>
  <p>some paragraph</p>
</div>
```

JSFiddle link - https://jsfiddle.net/dizzyramen/xfot3Lwv/2/

Comment: use `align-self: flex-start` on the image - this happens because *stretch* is the default behaviour (`align-items` on the *flex container* or `align-self` on the *flex item*)... see https://jsfiddle.net/947uqszj/

Comment: @kukkuz it's working! thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A default setting on a flex container is [`align-items: flex-start`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items).

In a row-direction container, this makes flex items, not having a defined height (e.g. `height: auto`), extend the full height of the container ([full explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44878379/3597276)).

In this particular case, however, the image is stretching to its fullest, and expanding the size of the container along with it.

The solution is to set a height limit on the container or override the default with `align-items: flex-start` on the container or `align-self: flex-start` on the item.

[jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/y4gzw5d1/)

```css
.item {
  display: flex;
}

img {
  width: 25%;
  align-self: start; /* new */
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <img src="https://png.pngtree.com/element_origin_min_pic/16/10/16/105802ebe43fe0f.jpg" />
  <p>some paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

here is another option:

- wrap your img in a div `<div class="image-wrapper">` and set manage the width in this node.
- asign `width: 100%;  height: auto;` to the `img` so it adjust proportionally to its parent.
- Here you have it in a snippet. Hope it helps.

```html
<div class="item">
    <div class="image-wrapper">
        <img
            src=
  "https://png.pngtree.com/element_origin_min_pic/16/10/16/105802ebe43fe0f.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <p>some paragraph</p>
</div>

<style>
.item{
  display:flex;
}
.image-wrapper {
  width: 25%; /* means 25% of .item */
}
img{
  width: 100%; /* means 100% of its parent .image-wrapper */
  height: auto;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I think I understood this approach but why did the width of .image-wrapper become that big so that you had to use width:25%?

Comment: If you do not set a specific width to a div, for example `.item`, the div has a default display block that fills all horizontal space.

Comment: An important part of the question was *why* `height: auto` wasn't working.

Answer (score -2):

It happens because, per default the tag `<img>`is inline. You need to change it to block or flex

Comment: Sergio, you cannot control the `display` value of flex items. Once you make an element a flex container, the `display` property on flex items is controlled by the flex algorithm. Attempts to set a `display` rule on flex items are ignored by the browser. So changing the `display` value of the `img` to `block` or `flex` wouldn't matter.

Comment: See the bottom of my answer here for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52471797/3597276