# Why flex container behaving like this

Tags: css, flexbox

when `display: flex` flex-container doesn't see's h1s bottom margin or top margin of h1 after flex-container,

but `display:inline-flex` see's

i want to understand why flex-container behaves like that

```css
h1 {
 color: #555;
}

.flex-container {
 margin:40px auto;
 padding: 10px;
 background-color: #ddd;
 border-radius: 5px;
 list-style: none;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
.flex-item {
 color: white;
 background-color: firebrick;
 border-radius: 5px;
 padding: 10px;
 margin: 10px;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 2rem;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}


.flex-container {
 display: flex; /* flex | inline-flex */
 // display: inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<h1>Flexbox</h1>
<ul class="flex-container">
    <li class="flex-item item-1">1</li>
    <li class="flex-item item-2">2</li>
    <li class="flex-item item-3">3</li>
    <li class="flex-item item-4">4</li>
    <li class="flex-item item-5">5</li>
    <li class="flex-item item-6">6</li>
    <li class="flex-item item-7">7</li>
    <li class="flex-item item-8">8</li>
</ul>
<h1>Bottom header</h1>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between display:inline-flex and display:flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27418104/difference-between-displayinline-flex-and-displayflex)

Comment: i think you should try taking some block for flex inline so that only inside the block the flex can be applied

Comment: @לבנימלכה in that question have no answer related to this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is default behaviour.

- `block` level elements vertical margins collapse.
- `inline` level elements vertical margins do not collapse.

According to the [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-container):

**inline-flex**

> A flex container establishes a new flex formatting context for its
>   contents. This is the same as establishing a block formatting context,
>   except that flex layout is used instead of block layout. For example,
>   floats do not intrude into the flex container, and the flex
>   container’s margins do not collapse with the margins of its contents.
>   Flex containers form a containing block for their contents exactly
>   like block containers do. [CSS21] The overflow property applies to
>   flex containers.

Comment: that's so weird

Comment: Yes I have never understood why block level elements collapse but it has been that way even before flex existed.

Answer (score 0):

That is how inline-block/flex works.

Look at this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/drba85t0/)

You are expecting the 2 divs to be on the same row, but instead the `display: block` property of the first div, is what is coursing this behaviour.

You need to add `display: inline-block` on the #one div to get you behaviour you are expecting.