# Prevent display: flex from stretching to full width of table cell

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a table with minimum width and variable number of columns. But the first column will always have the same content, container with couple icons stack together.

I need to use `display: flex` on the container, but this will stretch it to the full width of column, which will break my layout, please see example bellow:

```css
table {
  width: 500px;
  background-color: tan;
}

.stack-container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;  /* This is the troublemaker */
}

.icon1 {
  font-size: 22px;
}

.icon2 {
  position: absolute;
  right: -2px;
  bottom: -3px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span class="stack-container">
        <span class="icon1">A</span>
        <span class="icon2">o</span>
      </span>
    </td>
    <td>Two</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How to prevent the `.stack-container` with `display: flex` to stretch to full width of a table cell and make it stretch only to the width of it's content?

Example of what I want to achieve:

[image]

*Note1: When `.stack-container` is `display: block` it's stretched as well.*

*Note2: When `.stack-container` is `display: inline`, then it's not stretched to the full width of a table cell.*

Comment: Use `inline-flex` instead ...?

Comment: Yep, that works (didn't know about inline-flex). Thanks. Can you please add an explanation why are block elements stretched to the full width of table cell? I am really curious and I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be honest i am not sure what you want to do exactly but try to use `inline-flex` instead of `flex`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use these styles for the first td.

```
td:first-child {
  width: 1px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers and suggestions to use `display: inline-flex`, this was the value I was looking for.

I would like to elaborate on, why my `.stack-container` got stretched, when using `display: flex` (which created *block-level box*). Here is the answer, which describes it pretty well: [Difference between flex and inline-flex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27459133/1212547).

Especially this part here:

> The differences between block layout and inline layout are outside the scope of this question, but the one that stands out the most is auto width: block-level boxes stretch horizontally to fill their containing block, whereas inline-level boxes shrink to fit their contents.

Answer (score -1):

In this case, putting `display: flex` in `table` as well should make its contents not go full width. Check out this [pen](https://codepen.io/pen/).