# I've been trying to change my paragraph to block which is contained in a section that has elements displaying in inline-flex

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to change the paragraph with class errorDate to display as a block element immediately below  the input element [just as the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tlRx.jpg). The section is set to display as an inline-flex.

In the following css code i added display block in class errorDate and display inline-flex in date class which is the section element

```css
.date {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.errorDate {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<section class="date">
  <input type="datetime" class="mmname" id="mm" placeholder="MM" pattern="[01-31]{2}" required>

  <input type="datetime" class="yyname" id="yy" placeholder="YY" pattern="[00-99]{2}" required>
  <p class="errorDate"> Can't be blank </p>
  <!--CVC-->
  <div class="cVc">
    <label for="cvc" class="cvc">CVC</label>
    <input type="text" class="cvcname " id="cvcname" placeholder="eg. 123" pattern="[000-999]{3}" required>
    <p class="errorCvc">Can't be blank</p>

  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

This link, [What's the difference between display:inline-flex and display:flex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27418104/whats-the-difference-between-displayinline-flex-and-displayflex) may be worth reading.

In your case, move the `<p class="errorDate">The date can't be blank</p>` outside the `<section>`. It works nicely now.

```css
.date {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.errorDate {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<section class="date">
  <input type="datetime" class="mmname" id="mm" placeholder="MM" pattern="[01-31]{2}" required>
  <input type="datetime" class="yyname" id="yy" placeholder="YY" pattern="[00-99]{2}" required>
  <div class="cVc">
    <input type="text" class="cvcname " id="cvcname" placeholder="eg. 123" pattern="[000-999]{3}" required>
    <p class="errorCvc">The CVC can't be blank</p>
  </div>
</section>
<p class="errorDate">The date can't be blank</p>
```