# Bootstrap: d-inline-flex and flex-row-reverse combination is not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I want to make my html look like below.

[image]

```
  <p>Use .flex-row-reverse to right-align the direction:</p>
  <div class="d-inline-flex flex-row-reverse bg-secondary">
    <div class="p-2 bg-info">Flex item 1</div>
    <div class="p-2 bg-warning">Flex item 2</div>
    <div class="p-2 bg-primary">Flex item 3</div>
  </div>
```

But output is coming as

[image]

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27459204/4679429) might give you some explanation on your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `width`, otherwise the output will be the same as if you would set `width: auto;`.

See the snippet below.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<p>Use .flex-row-reverse to right-align the direction:</p>
<div class="d-inline-flex flex-row-reverse w-100">
  <div class="p-2 bg-info">Flex item 1</div>
  <div class="p-2 bg-warning">Flex item 2</div>
  <div class="p-2 bg-primary">Flex item 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Alternatively, changing `d-inline-flex` to `d-flex` could solve the issue as well :)

Comment: I want the Gray padding on the left of 'Flex item 3' to be white. That part is not working.

Comment: I edited my answer. Remove the class `bg-secondary`.