# Block Level Element vs Block Formatting Context

Tags: html, css

What is the difference between a HTML element that is a block level element and a HTML element that forms a block formatting context?

Can a HTML element be both a block level element and form a block formatting context?

Does being a block level element imply that it forms a block formatting context, or conversely, does forming a block formatting context imply that it must be a block level element?

In a similar vein, how does this translate to inline elements and elements that form an inline formatting context?

(For some context, I've been trying to read [Learn CSS Layout - The Pedantic Way](http://book.mixu.net/css/1-positioning.html) but it's been a bit challenging to follow Chapter 1)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that this answer uses the term "box" in lieu of "element", as CSS makes a distinction between elements and boxes. For the purposes of this answer, an HTML element is represented by a single box in CSS layout. In reality an element may generate any number of boxes (or none at all, as in `display: none`), but that's outside the scope of this question.

> Can a HTML element be both a block level element and form a block formatting context?

Yes. The criteria in which a block box (i.e. a block-level block container box) may establish a BFC are stated in [section 9.4.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting) of CSS2.1, namely:

- floats,
- absolutely positioned elements, and
- "block boxes with 'overflow' other than 'visible' (except when that value has been propagated to the viewport)" (as directly quoted from the spec)

> Does being a block level element imply that it forms a block formatting context, or conversely, does forming a block formatting context imply that it must be a block level element?

Neither:

1. The above answer implies that not all block boxes establish block formatting contexts. A block box with the CSS properties `display: block; overflow: visible; float: none; position: static` (or `position: relative`) does not establish a BFC.
2. Conversely, an inline-block is an example of a box that establishes a BFC, but is itself inline-level, not block-level.

> In a similar vein, how does this translate to inline elements and elements that form an inline formatting context?

An inline box is an inline-level box whose contents participate directly in its parent's inline formatting context (see [section 9.4.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#inline-formatting)). Notably, the *only* boxes that can establish inline formatting contexts are block container boxes.

The difference between an inline box and an inline-block is that an inline-block's contents participate in the BFC that it establishes, not in the parent's IFC. Instead, only the inline-block itself participates in its parent's IFC.

Comment: Should point 1 say "A block box with the CSS properties `display: block; overflow: visible; float:none; position:static;` does not establish a BFC?

Comment: @Alohci: Indeed. Thanks.

Comment: This might be a silly question but what determines whether a box is block level? Is it whether that box has display: block applied to it? And if so, what does a block level box imply?

Comment: @wmock: A block-level box is any box that participates in some other element's BFC (whether or not it *establishes* its own), or more simply, participates in *block layout*. It can be determined by a number of things, see [§9.7](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo), but it mostly comes down to the `display` property. Any of `block`, `table`, or `flex` generates a block-level box (a block box, a block-level table, or a block-level flex container respectively). Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24313271/display-property-differences-for-inline-something)

Comment: @wmock: If I'm not wrong, a block-level box does not imply anything else other than the fact that it participates in block layout.

Comment: @BoltClock just to confirm, participating in block layout simply means that the box and its sibling boxes will be stacked vertically on top of each other, right?

Comment: @wmock: Yes, in normal flow. Things are a little bit different once you yank a block-level box out of normal flow (e.g. by floating or absposing it).

Comment: @BoltClock in your answer, you mentioned how a box can form a BFC - on the other hand, how does a box form a inline formatting context?

Comment: @wmock: A block container box (a block box, an inline-block or a table cell) automatically forms inline formatting contexts for its inline descendants as necessary.