# How can I write this layout with flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How can I write this layout with flexbox?
[image: Responsive question]

There is my solution but doesn't work properly. I can fix with CSS grid but IE11 doesn't support properly.

Do you have any suggestion/solution?
https://codepen.io/hamzaerbay/pen/KXJEWJ?editors=1100

```
<div class="box-wrapper">
    <div class="box title">Web Developer, Designer</div>
  <div class="avatar-meta box">
    <div class="avatar">
      <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/jsa/128.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="box meta">
      <ul>
        <li>5 Average rating</li>
        <li>20,375 Reviews</li>
        <li>208,161 </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box desc">
I'm a web designer and developer with a great passion for building beautiful new things from scratch.
    </div>
</div>  
.box{
  border:1px solid #ccc;
}
.box-wrapper{
  max-height:200px; 
  display:flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
  max-width:100%;
}
.avatar-meta{
  order:-1;
  flex-direction:column;
}
.avatar{
  img{
    width:120px;
    height:120px;
    border-radius:50%;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
  .box-wrapper{
    flex-flow: column nowrap
  }
  box{
    flex:1 0 auto;
    width:100%;
  }
  .avatar-meta {
    display:flex;
    flex-flow:row wrap;
    min-height:140px;
  }
  .meta{
    flex:1 0 auto;
  }
  .title{
    order:-1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to use [grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) instead of flexbox?

Comment: @Duannx I did with css grid but it doesn't work on ie11 
https://codepen.io/hamzaerbay/pen/BwMBZZ

Comment: Ya. It does not work in IE 11. But i think there is no way to do it with flexbox. Maybe you can done it just by `float` and `media`

Comment: If you can set a fixed height on the outer most container, then yes, you can do it with Flexbox. This mean that in desktop mode, when content in the either column exceed that fixed height, 1 or both elements will get an inner scroll.

Comment: Btw, what's wrong with your codepen?

Comment: @LGSon I don't want fixed height or max-height on .box-wrapper class

Comment: Let me know if my answer were helpful and can be accepted? ... and if not, is there something I can adjust, add or explain?

Comment: @HamzaErbay CSS Grid first browser support was IE. For 2D layouts, use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on not have to set a fixed height or using CSS Grid or script, a combination of `float` and Flexbox is likely the only way to accomplish that.

Move the `avatar-meta` element first in the markup, and for the *desktop* layout, we use `float: left` on it, give it a width and then use *BFC** and a left margin on the `title`/`desc`.

For the *mobile* we use Flexbox, and with its `order` property moves the `title` to the top.

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eGXQPO)

Stack snippet

```css
.box{
  border:1px solid #ccc;
}
.title, .desc{
  margin-left: 200px;
}
.avatar-meta{
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
}
.avatar img {
    width:120px;
    height:120px;
    border-radius:50%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
  .box-wrapper{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .avatar-meta {
    display:flex;
    min-height: 140px;
  }
  .title {
    order: -1;
  }
  .title, .desc {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .avatar-meta {
    float: none;
    width: auto;
  }
  .meta {
    flex-grow: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box-wrapper">
  <div class="avatar-meta box">
    <div class="avatar">
      <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/jsa/128.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="box meta">
      <ul>
        <li> 4.6 Average rating</li>
        <li>25,375 Reviews</li>
        <li>208,161 Students</li>
        <li>3 Courses</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box title">Web Developer, Designer, and Teacher</div>
  <div class="box desc">
I'm a web designer and developer with a great passion for building beautiful new things from scratch. I've been building websites since 2007 and also have a Master's degree in Engineering. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum laboriosam magni eum, error amet ex recusandae nostrum, temporibus quam in est nesciunt voluptas tempore velit aliquam beatae iste? Nihil, labore.

    </div>
</div>
```

---

- BFC, which stands for *block formatting context* and here is a few resources:

  - [How does the CSS Block Formatting Context work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6196725/how-does-the-css-block-formatting-context-work)
  - [Block Level Element vs Block Formatting Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35111906/block-level-element-vs-block-formatting-context)
  - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context