# Why overflow:hidden can’t prevent margin collapsing in sibling divs as display:inline-block?

Tags: css

As far as I know, `overflow: hidden`  and `display:inline-block` can both establish a new blocking format context,and blocking format context can prevent margin collapse.

But `overflow:hidden` can’t prevent margin collapsing between sibling divs as `display:inline-block`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    .div1 {
      background-color: red;
      margin-bottom: 100px;
    }
    
    .div2 {
      background-color: orange;
      margin-top: 200px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="div1">div1</div>
  <div class="div2">div2</div>
</body>

</html>
```

I wished the `overflow:hidden` on .div2 can establish a block format context and the margin between .div1 and .div2 should be 300px.  But it didn't work. Why?

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: show the code of such sitatuion. There is no margin collapsing between inline-block element with or without oveflow hidden

Comment: @disinfor why overflow:hidden can’t prevent collapsing margin as display:inline-block? they both establish a block format context.

Comment: @TemaniAfif hi, I just added the codes. Now I understand that no margin collapsing between inline-block elements. But I still don’t know why overflow:hidden won’t work as I expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Margins between sibling block formatting contexts established by block boxes don't intrude into either context, so margin collapsing is allowed to happen as normal. The kind of margin collapsing that's prevented by creating a new BFC is that between the parent that establishes the BFC, and any in-flow block-level child boxes.

The reason margins between inline-blocks don't collapse is not because they establish block formatting contexts, but because margins between siblings only collapse when they are block-level boxes, never when they are inline-level boxes (inline, inline-block, inline-table or whatever).

Comment: Thx. Now I almost get it.  But I still have one question. I found that `display:inline-block`  elements are block format context but not inline format context. So I'm confused about if they should also have margin collapsing.

Comment: @T.T: Yeah, that's a common source of confusion. Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35111906/block-level-element-vs-block-formatting-context/35111972#35111972) make things clearer for you?

Comment: Thx. So inline-block elements are inline-level boxes as a result of that their contents don’t participate in their parents’ IFC?