# In flexbox, why do we define the container and not the elements themselves?

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to understand the flex property.

Why do we apply `float` and `display: inline-block` to the elements that are nested inside a container, while with `display: flex`, we define the container itself?
How can the elements inside be `display:block` and still be positioned on the same row?

```css
.flex {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .flex {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

#aaa {
  border: 3px solid black;
  flex: 2;
}

#aa {
  border: 3px solid black;
  flex: 1;
}

#a {
  border: 3px solid black;
  flex: 1;
}

#bbb {
  width: 300px;
}

#ccc {
  float: left;
  border: 5px solid yellow;
  width: 200px;
}

#ddd {
  clear: both;
}

.one {
  background: red;
  height: 50px
}

.two {
  background: green;
  height: 50px
}

.tree {
  background: blue;
  height: 50px
}

#eee {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class=flex>
  <div id=a class="one">flex</div>
  <div id=aa class="two">flex</div>
  <div id=aaa class="tree">flex</div>
</div>
<div class=block>
  <div id=bbb class="one">block</div>
  <div id=bbb class="two">block</div>
  <div id=bbb class="tree">block</div>
</div>
<div class=float>
  <div id=ccc class="one">float</div>
  <div id=ccc class="two">float</div>
  <div id=ccc class="tree">float</div>
</div>
<div class=block>
  <div id=ddd class="one">block</div>
  <div id=ddd class="two">block</div>
  <div id=ddd class="tree">block</div>
</div>
<div class=block>
  <div id=eee class="one">block</div>
  <div id=eee class="two">block</div>
  <div id=eee class="tree">block</div>
</div>
```

[CodePen demo](http://codepen.io/navehazan/pen/EXpOXB)

Comment: Any reason why you removed the [css] and [css3] tags from your question?

Answer (score 7):

> In flexbox, why do we define the container and not the elements themselves?

The reason is twofold:

1. Flex containers are the only things flex items can appear as children of, since only flex containers generate flex layout.
2. Unlike anonymous block boxes and anonymous table boxes, there are no such things as anonymous flex container boxes.

So, a hypothetical `display: flex-item` wouldn't work unless the element's parent was a flex container, and since every child of a flex container automatically becomes a flex item anyway, this makes such a display type completely redundant.

Block-level and inline-level boxes, on the other hand, [exist in many, many forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24313271/display-property-differences-for-inline-something/24313727#24313727). Even *flex containers* can appear in block-level and inline-level forms, as `display: flex` and `display: inline-flex` respectively. Furthermore, [`display: block` and `display: inline-block` actually have a lot in common](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17500280/what-is-the-difference-between-block-and-inline-block-with-width-100/17500310#17500310), as they are both block containers. The only difference is that one is block-level and the other is inline-level (and the latter always generates a block formatting context, but that's not pertinent here).

So `display: block` and `display: inline-block` are actually very similar to `display: flex` and `display: inline-flex` respectively in that regard (see [Difference between display:inline-flex and display:flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27418104/difference-between-displayinline-flex-and-displayflex/27459133#27459133)), the difference being that the former pair handles block layout or inline layout (see [section 9.2 of the CSS2 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#box-gen)), and the latter pair handles exclusively flex layout.

If you're asking why flexbox was designed this way, that's something only the CSSWG can answer with certainty, but I can provide an educated guess based on what I've stated above: Since block-level and inline-level boxes can exist in so many different forms for various internal layout types (block, table, flex, grid, etc), defining flex-level counterparts for every single layout type would become extremely unwieldy, even if they *did* introduce a concept of anonymous flex container boxes which would allow elements to exist as flex items in their own right. This is why css-display-3 [redefines the `display` property](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-display-3/#the-display-properties) to take the form of `<display-outside> <display-inside>` along with special and legacy values — to accommodate new layout types without having to redefine entire sets of keywords to go along with them.

Your flex items are `display: block` simply because that's their specified value of `display`. But they are *laid out* as flex items, which always obey a set of rules in flex layout, which are loosely based on a combination of various elements of block *and* inline layout without falling squarely within the domain of either one. This is similar to how a float or an absolutely positioned element cannot be inline even if you specify `display: inline` or `display: inline-block` — because floats and absolutely positioned elements always participate in block layout, never inline layout.

Speaking of floats, FYI, floats participate in block formatting contexts, and are therefore part of a certain subset of block layout. They follow a float model, but the float model is integrated with the rest of block layout rather than existing as a completely separate layout type.

Comment: I wouldn't even compare `flex` to `block` or `inline-block` since it's not the same at all, but I would compare it to `display:table` because that it something much closer to it in essence, since they both define a block which supposedly have children which should behave in a very specific manner.

Comment: @vsync: But, like I said, block and inline-block are block containers, whose children *also* have to behave in a very specific manner. A table box can support a variety of internal table box types at once; a block container can only ever contain block-level boxes *or* inline-level boxes, just as a flex container can only ever contain flex items. What *really* sets flexbox apart from block, inline-block and table is the fact that there is no flex-item display type, because only flex containers can have flex items. Now that I think about it, perhaps that's what the asker is really interested in.

Comment: @vsync: But the comparison to tables has merit - for a different reason. I'll edit my answer later. I really shouldn't be up at this time of day.

Comment: I think OP wants to know the `why` I guess. why the parent control how the children behaves, but I think that is a question which only the committee who came up with the implementation should address.

Comment: @vsync: I rewrote my answer.